# How do I restrict download access to a CSV file created using PHP?

Tags: php, csv

## Objective:

I need to create a CSV file via PHP but limit download access to the member responsible for the creation of the file.

## Context:

Website members have the option of outputting their profile data to a CSV file. The created CSV file represents a potential privacy issue. I'm concerned that if two members simultaneously create the CSV file, an overlap could result in one member's data being revealed to another.

## What I've tried:

```
<?php
$list = array (
    array('1', '2', '3', '4'),
    array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
?>

<!--File is in root-->
<a href="/file.csv">Download file.csv</a>
```

## My question:

1. How do I limit download access to the member that creates the CSV file?
2. Can an overlap occur between members when creating the CSV file since it's essentially a shared file?

My idea so far is to give each CSV file a unique name rather rewriting the same file. That'll solve the the overlap issue though the files are still accessible when targeted in a browser. I can assign the CSV files to restricted folder but it's probably more ideal to destroy the file once its downloaded.

Is there a better approach to all of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to just output the data to `stdout` and send the proper headers when your script is called.

Per example, you have this HTML link:

```
<a href="download_csv.php">Download as CSV</a>
```

In `download_csv.php`, you just do:

```
$list = array (
    array('1', '2', '3', '4'),
    array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
);

// Send the proper headers
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=results.csv');

// Open stdout instead of an actual file
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
```

This'll fix both of your problems.

Comment: I've tested this and it works great. Thanks for your explanation and example on the use of stdout.